# How to test remotely using WebARonARKit and three.ar.js

Tags: three.js, arkit

I'm building an app for the iPad using WebARonARKit and three.ar.js. I have WebARonARKit installed on my iPad and I got the demo projects to work.

How do I test my own code on my desktop in a browser whilst I am building my project?

I tried it on Safari Technology Preview but that didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for by one way to do it is on your MAC, under Safari "Develop" menu, select your iPad then select the WebARonARKit web instance.

*Your iPad has to be connected to your MAC though.

hth!

-Sylvain

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a way to make changes in my text editor and reload the webpage on my iPad or my desktop and see the changes I make as I go.